# Mastercoin API - what to use?

Tags: wallet, development, api, daemon, omni

I am interested in communicating with the Mastercoin network through an API to control various assets. In Bitcoin, I would run the Bitcoin daemon and use the documented API. For Mastercoin, I'm hearing conflicting opinions - either using [omniwallet](https://github.com/mastercoin-MSC/omniwallet), [mastercoin-tools](https://github.com/grazcoin/mastercoin-tools) or [mastercore](https://github.com/mastercoin-MSC/mastercore).

What is the best approach to take to communicate with the Mastercoin network through an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most easy way to do this would be through Omniwallet API.
mastercoin-tools is deprecated and should not be used.

If you want the better security achieved by running a local instance, use Master Core.

Comment: Hmm, Master Core appears to come with a big warning of "This software is EXPERIMENTAL software for TESTNET TRANSACTIONS only. USE ON MAINNET AT YOUR OWN RISK.". So is that still the preferred choice for people wishing to run services using Mastercoin?

Comment: Yup! You know, liability and stuff :) 

Also, Mastercore is being renamed Omnicore.